# After successful(?) installation of ask-cli, I'm getting a deployment error where it says invalid json. How do I fix this?

Tags: command-line-interface, aws-cli, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

yashadnani$ npm install -g ask-cli

/usr/local/bin/ask -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ask-cli/bin/ask.js

- ask-cli@1.3.1

updated 1 package in 1.695s

Yashs-MacBook-Pro:~ yashadnani$ ask init

Invalid json: /Users/yashadnani/.ask/cli_config

Yashs-MacBook-Pro:~ yashadnani$ sudo npm install -g ask-cli

/usr/local/bin/ask -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ask-cli/bin/ask.js

- ask-cli@1.3.1

updated 1 package in 1.679s

Yashs-MacBook-Pro:~ yashadnani$ ask init

Invalid json: /Users/yashadnani/.ask/cli_config

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by deleting the `.ask/` folder :

```
rm -rf .ask/
```

And then reinstalling the cli from scratch using

```
npm install ask-cli -g
```

And then you can run `ask init` to complete the setup.